# Does anyone know what this means when enabling unattended upgrades?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

Does anyone know what this means when enabling unattended upgrades.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades
```

I mean the line that says:

```
"origin=Debian, codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security"
```

Is it alright just to click okay and unattended-upgrades will work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your question is related to Debian, it's the configuration which defines which packages automatically are going to be upgrade.

Each package has some meta data, e.g:

```
Origin: Ubuntu
codename: Xenial
label: Security
```

it means packages that are from Ubuntu and specific to "xenial" with the label of "security" are going to be upgraded automatically.

For Ubuntu you should have something similar to:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {    
    // ${distro_id} and ${distro_codename} will be automatically expanded
    "${distro_id} stable";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
//  "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-proposed-updates";
};
```

[More info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) about configuration, if you're running Ubuntu follow this link and you should be fine.

Comment: I am running xubuntu 16.04.2. So at configuration I should change it to "origin=Ubuntu, codename=${distro_codename},label=Security" or "origin=Ubuntu, codename=Zesty,label=Security"?

Comment: For code names use ${distro_codename} instead of Zesty, 16.04 is Xenial.